# javascript onmouseover applied to divs of different class?

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I'm trying to learn a little bit about javascript and how it works. I can manage to hash out some basic commands, but I'm trying to turn this thread layout into a javascript onmouseover command for crossbrowser compatibility on a message board with code that will not allow css hover properties to work in IE unless they are in an "a" tag. Keep in mind, I can't change the web page, only this small chunk of a layout, so I cannot set a doctype to make this css work in IE.

Here is what I have without js: http://jsfiddle.net/KRArE/

```
#postbody p::first-letter {
letter-spacing:1px;
line-height:0.5;
font-size: 30px;
font-family:'Lovers Quarrel', cursive;
}
#ruwhole {
width: 420px;
height: 420px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
#ruwhole:hover .postbox {
-webkit-transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
-o-transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 400px;
height: 370px;
border:10px solid #eeeddb;
}
#ruwhole .postbox {
-webkit-transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
-o-transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
position:absolute;
width: 400px;
height:370px;
top: -390px;
border:10px solid #eeeddb;
}
#ruwhole:hover .statbar {
-webkit-transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
-o-transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
}
#ruwhole .statbar {
-webkit-transition: 1s all ease-in;
-moz-transition: 1s all ease-in;
-o-transition: 1s all ease-in;
transition: 1s all ease-in;
position: absolute;
bottom: -30px;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
}
#postbody em {
color: #841b1f;
}
```

I can change the qualities of the div that the mouseover is applied to, but how would I go about applying a mouseover js command to one div and have the changes appear in other divs? I want the user to be able to mouse over the layout as a whole and have the two divs that are off screen, slide in, as they do with the css functions. I'm totally at a loss here!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using jQuery and the [jQuery Easing plugin](https://github.com/gdsmith/jquery.easing)

I'm pretty sure this would be a safer alternative to CSS transitions.

Using jQuery you can attach a hover event to the outer div ("#ruwhole") and then specify the mouseover and mouseout animations for the inner divs (".postbox" and ".statbar"). The easing plugin gives you more animation effects to choose from than jQuery alone.

The JavaScript itself might look like below. Here's a working example based on your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/david_i_smith/HbhFK/)

(Sorry I'm unable to test in IE.)

Hope this helps.

```
$(function () {

    var ruwhole = $('#ruwhole'),
        postbox = ruwhole.find('.postbox'),
        statbar = ruwhole.find('.statbar');

    ruwhole.hover(
        function () {
            postbox
                .animate(
                    { top: '0' }, {
                        duration: '1',
                        easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
                    }
                );
            statbar
                .animate(
                    { bottom: '0' }, {
                        duration: '1',
                        easing: 'easeInQuad'
                    }
            );
        },
        function () {
            postbox
                .animate(
                    { top: '-390' }, {
                        duration: '1',
                        easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
                    }
                );
            statbar
                .animate(
                    { bottom: '-30' }, {
                        duration: '1',
                        easing: 'easeInQuad'
                    }
            );
        }
    );

});
```